# About the optimal resolution and refresh rate of a monitor

Tags: display, resolution, refresh-rate

I recently got a monitor able to go up to 144Hz, and while browsing its settings today I noticed that in the information tab it says the optimal resolution is 1920x1080 at 120Hz, and not 1920x1080 at 144Hz.

I wasn't really able to find any information about this, and my question boils down to: why is the optimal refresh rate shown in the settings tab lower than the 144Hz the monitor can push? Does it make a difference that I keep the monitor at a constant 144Hz vs 120Hz? Should I expect bad things to happen? Since the high refresh rate was the highlight of this monitor, it really seems weird to me that the maker chose 120Hz as the optimal rate.

Specific monitor (BenQ XL2411Z) on its maker's website: http://shop.benq.us/monitors/gaming/xl2411z.html

Settings screen:
[image]

Comment: My guess is, Just because it CAN go to 144hz, doesn't necessarily mean it'll be at it's peak when it's on that setting.

Comment: You need to provide specifics.  We can't confirm if you actually have a 144hz monitor ( that is an odd frequency by the way ) so we cannot explain the behavior.

Comment: @Ramhound Added link to the monitor for the specific info.

Comment: Optimal frequency for that monitor is 100/120/144 MHz based on a setting on the monitor; so just change it to 144 MHz

Comment: I switched to 120Hz for a bit. No idea if it's my imagination, but the colors do seem a bit more pronounced and clean. Perhaps this might be the cause 120Hz is advertised as optimal? Being some sort of perfect balance between speedy refresh rate and color quality? I have no idea if what I said here even makes sense though.

Comment: @Ramhound right, so it depends on the settings currently used. I'm on a standard setting; I'll try something gaming-specific later and see if it switches to 144 as recommended.

Comment: All 3 frequencies are optimal though.

Comment: @Ramhound added the settings menu where it lists the optimal I was talking about.

Comment: Yes; Just change it to 144 all 3 values according to the product website are optimal

Answer (score 1):

Your monitor *supports* 144Hz.  However, your graphics card - which pushes the content - does not.  In all honesty, I dont believe the human eye would be able to distinguish between 120 and 144Hz.

Comment: How did you link what the monitor's settings menu (see the picture above, it's not Windows' settings menu) says to the GPU (about which I haven't mentioned anything so far)? I don't believe this is in any way accurate, especially since the GPU (GTX 760) pushes well over 200 frames per second in the games I bought the monitor for. Which is over 144 frames per second which in turn is what 144Hz can display.

Comment: FPS and refresh rates are totally independent of each other.  Read this.  http://www.tweakguides.com/Graphics_7.html

Comment: What's written there only further supports my claim above. Please explain to me yourself how my GPU does not support a monitor with an 144Hz refresh rate, I might not be getting it. My GPU is a reference model, so the specs set by nvidia apply to it, in case you need them:  http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-760/specifications

Answer (score -1):

I'd be amazed if any regular human being could tell the difference between 120Hz or 144Hz. Most LCDs run fine at 60Hz, which is already more than twice the refresh rate of a movie. 
So if your computer is running fine with 120Hz and chose it as the optimal setting, stick to the old computer wisdom: if it ain't broke, don't try to fix it.