# Monitor refresh rate evolution?

Tags: display, refresh-rate

I believe the refresh rate of a screen has been doubled every decade: 30hz, 60hz, 120hz and maybe 240hz would the norm in the next decade.

But this has been confusing debate (usually in gaming forum) especially after I read https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4798572/

Does the Hz (CFF) talked in the article draw any parallel with monitor refresh/shutter rate stuff? (in the sense that human eye still have hard time following flies movement unlike those birds).

EDIT: (to put the some context)

2000-2009 : I use PS2 and PS3, hence 30hz CRT, in 2009 first 120hz LCD produced and according to the article human eyes are ~40hz.

2010-now : I use PC, hence 60hz LCD and this new year upgraded to 120hz Freesync monitor (this is average birds CFF in the article).

First 240hz monitor produced in 2017, this supposedly matches those of flying insect compound eyes.

related question: [About the optimal resolution and refresh rate of a monitor](https://superuser.com/questions/862364/about-the-optimal-resolution-and-refresh-rate-of-a-monitor?rq=1)

Googling around more info it turn out 30Hz/60hz has been with us for long  time as noted in comment below, and only within last decade 120-240hz showing up, by now some (Pro and Expert included) claim human eye has range of 20-120hz CFF, or even 1000hz. It's confusing!

Comment: I have never seen a computer monitor that operated at 30Hz. For the last 30 years I have used computers the *default* refresh rate for a computer monitor was 60hz. 30Hz is a *television* refresh rate that computers might have been compatible with but that is about it.

Comment: I did say screen.. but point is by average its doubled. I stand corrected